# Is the intederminate form: $-\infty/\infty$ valid for L'Hôpital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

in my calculus course, we learned that in order to use L'Hôpital's Rule, the function must have the form of either $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$. However, I wanted to ask if the forms $-\infty/\infty$ or $\infty/-\infty$ are also valid for L'Hôpital's Rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can , But you must rembember that you can use L'Hôpital's Rule will work only when the limit exist.